# how to change one class while focusing on another class

Tags: html, css

I want when i click dot-1 then dot-2 height and width get 24px but when i click on dot 2 again it's height width becomes 60px again

```html
 <ul class="paralx-position">
  <li class="paralx-dots"><img src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div2" id="img2" tabindex="0"></img></li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div3" id="img3" tabindex="0"></image></li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-2" class="Active" data-box="div1"  id="img1"  tabindex="0"><span class="icon-position"><image src="images/logos/noun_build_1909132.svg" class="icon"></image></span></image></li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div4" id="img4"  tabindex="0"></image></li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div5" id="img5" tabindex="0"></image></li>
  <li class="paralx-dots"><image src="images/Circle 1- Blue .svg" class="paralx-dot-1" data-box="div6" id="img6" tabindex="0"></image></li>
</ul>
```

```css
.paralx-dot-1:focus {
    animation-name:bright-dot;
 animation-duration:1.5s;
 height: 24.75px;
 width: 24.75px;
   outline: none;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

@keyframes bright-dot {
 from {transform:scale(1,1);}
 to {transform:scale(2,2);}
}

.paralx-dot-1:focus + .paralx-dot-2{

 height:24px;
 width:24px;           (THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING)

    }
```

---

I want to animate one class while focusing on another class, but it's not working

```css
.paralx-dot-1{
height:24.75px;
width:24.75px;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
outline:none;
}

.paralx-dot-2{
height:61.18px;
width:60.26px;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
right:18px;
position:relative
}
```

Comment: Reword your question. and clarify your points. I dont get what your saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so there are a few things going on here:

- Change `image` to `img`, you don't *have* to do this because it is aliased but `image` is never used and is only around for legacy reasons
- The CSS selector `a + b` would require the elements to be next to each other, but they are not as both are in their own `li`.
- Most of your elements are `paralx-dot-1` with one `paralx-dot-2`. If you are expecting all `paralx-dot-1` to change `paralx-dot-2` then it will not work. With CSS you can only affect elements inside or after the one in the selector. So focus on the last element will not affect one before it.

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background: green;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
}

li:hover {
  background: yellow;
}

li:hover + li {
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

As you can see in [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gydMZW), the HTML and CSS above is slightly different to what you need but should point you in the right direction. So in this example where `li:hover + li` makes the next sibling (if one exists) bigger and red, you could animate it instead.